# complex hull script in matlab with cross product

Tags: matlab

For school I have to write a script to get a convex hull given an array of x and y. To test if my code works I made up some values for x and y, and plotted the graph. The plot is clearly not a convex, but I'm unsure what I did wrong. I looked at the formula for the cross product and even calculated it by hand, but I came to the same answer for the cross product of the particular vectors as matlab did. I looked at the possibility that the formula used was incorrect, this is unlikely cause I found the same formula at two independent sources. I copied the code I used below. Thanks in advance!
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan, source for formula under section algorithm.

```
x =[2 4 5 3 9 10]
y =[-10 8 4 -5 9 10] 
plot(x,y,'*')
[min_y,i] = min(y);
pivot = [x(i),y(i)];
number = i
%getting the angle
x(i) = [];
y(i) = [];
delta_x = x - ones(1,length(x))*pivot(1);
delta_y = y - ones(1,length(y))*pivot(2);
theta = atan2d(delta_y,delta_x);
%sorting without losing the position
c = [];
x_new= [];
y_new = [];
for n = 1:length(theta)
    [min_theta, d] = min(theta);
    c = [c d];
    x_new = [x_new x(d)];
    y_new = [y_new y(d)];
    theta(d) = [1000]; %random value need to be higher than 180 degrees
end
x_new = [pivot(1) x_new pivot(1) x_new(1)];
y_new = [pivot(2) y_new pivot(2) y_new(1)];
%using cross product in this exercise none of the lines are collinear
%If the result is 0, the points are collinear;
%if it is positive, the three points constitute a "left turn" or counter-clockwise orientation,
%otherwise a "right turn" or clockwise orientation (for counter-clockwise numbered points)
%source wiki
n_bad = [];
n_good = [];
x_new
y_new
for n = 1:(length(x_new)-3) %this caused by how the array x_new and y_new contain duplicates
    x_new(n+1)
    cross_product = (x_new(n+1) - x_new(n))*(y_new(n+2)-y_new(n))-((y_new(n+1)-y_new(n))*(x_new(n+2)-x_new(n)))
    if cross_product < 0
        n_bad = [n_bad n+1];
    end
    if cross_product > 0 %this is unnecassaray can be used for skipping making the program faster
        n_good = [n_good n+1]
    end
end
%in case I did something wrong the graph can be plotted here:
figure
x_good = [pivot(1) x_new(n_good) pivot(1)];
y_good = [pivot(2) y_new(n_good) pivot(2)];
plot(x_good,y_good)
%to get the same index as the input
if number>1
    n_good = n_good + 1;
    n = sort([n_good number]);
else 
    n = [number n_good];
end
n
```

Comment: Your cross-product calculation is fine. The contents of your for loop do not match the pseudocode on the Wikipedia page. For instance, your code does not contain a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments your loop did not have the correct nested while loop. Here is a modified script built using yours that works for me. In the end I test it on MATLAB's own convex hull function.

First I added a MATLAB function

```
function [ value ] = ccw( p1,p2,p3,x,y )
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
    value=(x(p2)-x(p1))*(y(p3)-y(p1))-(y(p2)-y(p1))*(x(p3)-x(p1));
end
```

Next the modified script

```
clear all
x =[2 4 5 3 9 10]
y =[-10 8 4 -5 9 10] 


x=[4,-3,8,12,4,-4,4,1,2,8,6] %additional test
y=[5,8,-6,1,4,7,8,-4,4,2,1]
[min_y,i] = min(y);
pivot = [x(i),y(i)];
number = i
%getting the angle
% x(i) = [];
% y(i) = [];
delta_x = x - ones(1,length(x))*pivot(1);
delta_y = y - ones(1,length(y))*pivot(2);
theta = atan2d(delta_y,delta_x);
%sorting without losing the position
c = [];
x_new= [];
y_new = [];
for n = 1:length(theta)
    [min_theta, d] = min(theta);
    c = [c d];
    x_new = [x_new x(d)];
    y_new = [y_new y(d)];
    theta(d) = [1000]; %random value need to be higher than 180 degrees
end
 x_new = [x_new x_new(1)];
 y_new = [y_new y_new(1)];
%using cross product in this exercise none of the lines are collinear
%If the result is 0, the points are collinear;
%if it is positive, the three points constitute a "left turn" or counter-clockwise orientation,
%otherwise a "right turn" or clockwise orientation (for counter-clockwise numbered points)
%source wiki
n_bad = [];
n_good = [1,2];
figure(1)
plot(x_new,y_new,'-o')
for n = 3:(length(x_new)) %this caused by how the array x_new and y_new contain duplicates
    %cross_product = (x_new(n+1) - x_new(n))*(y_new(n+2)-y_new(n))-((y_new(n+1)-y_new(n))*(x_new(n+2)-x_new(n)))
%     if cross_product < 0
%         n_bad = [n_bad n+1];
%     end
    len=length(n_good);
    while (ccw(n_good(len-1),n_good(len),n,x_new,y_new) < 0 && length(n_good)>=2) %this is unnecassaray can be used for skipping making the program faster
        n_good(length(n_good))=[]
        len=length(n_good);
    end
    n_good=[n_good n]
end
%in case I did something wrong the graph can be plotted here:
figure(2)
x_good = [pivot(1) x_new(n_good) pivot(1)];
y_good = [pivot(2) y_new(n_good) pivot(2)];
plot(x_good,y_good,'-o',x,y,'b*')
%to get the same index as the input
if number>1
    n_good = n_good + 1;
    n = sort([n_good number]);
else 
    n = [number n_good];
end
figure(3)
k = convhull(x,y);
plot(x(k),y(k),'r-',x,y,'b*')
```

Comment: First of all, thank you. But what is exactly the problem in my code? I ask this because  it is for me more beneficial to understand the problem than exactly having a working program.

Comment: Hi Bjorn, so you had to make a data structure called stack https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type) for this problem, and at every iteration you have to pop things off the stack if the triangle area condition is not met and then push the newest element. So the two main problems were your code didnt implement a stack structure and second the operations needed require two loops and yours had only one. It might be helpful to run the two codes side by side in small steps and see how they differ